# How to use linux .debug file with Ghidra

Tags: linux, ghidra

I have an ELF64 binary that comes with `*.sym` and `.debug`. From my understanding this is something akin to PDB. While IDA loads it automatically, it fails to process it. I was wondering if Ghidra will fare better but I can't seems to find a way to do so. [This issue](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/3513) does say it should be in but I cant figure it out:

```
Skipping DWARF import because a precondition was not met:
TheMainBinary has more DIE records (2018267) than limit of 2000000
Manually re-run the DWARF analyzer after adjusting the options or start it via Dwarf_ExtractorScript
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ghidra can in fact parse the `.debug` section and DWARF information in general, but the error message you posted indicates that it is refusing to do so, because of the too large number of records. It also gives you the two options to explicitly run the analysis nonetheless:

1. Running the Auto Analysis Step with custom configuration
2. Running a separate script.

The first option specifically means:
In the CodeBrowser view of the specific binary, click `Analysis` in the top bar, then `Auto Analyze '$binaryname'`. In the resulting list of analyzers scroll down to DWARF which should then look like this screenshot

[image]

change the `2000000` highlighted to anything higher than `2018267`, hit analyze, and Ghidra should now rerun the auto analysis but properly import the DWARF information and not skip it like before.